# Holomorphic function such that $f(\frac{1}{n})=\frac{1}{n+1}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $U$ be an open connected neighborhood of $0$ in $\Bbb{C}$ and $f$ a holomorphic function on $U$.
>
> The exercise is to prove that if $f(\frac{1}{n})=\frac{1}{n+1}$ for all $n\ge 1$ then $f(z)=\frac{z}{z+1}$ on $U$.

So I did it using the function $g:\Bbb{C} \setminus\{-1\}\to \Bbb{C}$ such that $g(z)=\frac{z}{1+z}$ so $g$ is holomorphic on $\Bbb{C} \setminus\{-1\}$, now as $U$ is open we can find a disc $D(0,r)\subset U$ for $r$ so that $r<1$.

Therefore, using analytic continuation we have $f=g$ on $D(0,r)$.

My main problem is now to prove that $U\subset\Bbb{C} \setminus\{-1\}$. Perhaps, I can say that if $-1\in U$ we can find a path from $0$ to $-1$ but not sure how can I continue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** If you assume by contradiction that $-1 \in U$, then prove first that $f(z)=g(z)$ on $U \backslash \{-1\}$.

Then use the fact that $f$ is continuous at $-1$, and hence 
$$f(-1)=\lim_{z \to -1} \frac{z}{z+1}=\infty$$

Comment: Hence $f$ cannot be holomorphic on a set containing $-1$, and therefore $-1\notin U$.

Comment: @Arthur Actually $f$ cannot be holomorphic on a connected set containing $-1$ ;)

Comment: Thanks to prove that $f(z)=g(z)$ on $U\setminus{-1}$ how can I do that ? Just the same argument as I did using analytic continuation? So I just need to say as $f$ is continuons then she admits a finite limit at $-1$ wich cannot be the case, rigt ?

Comment: @JeSuis Exactly as in your post ;). $g$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb C \backslash \{ -1 \}$ implies that $g$ is holomorphic on $U \backslash \{ -1 \}$. $f$ is also holomorphic on $U \backslash \{ -1 \}$ and they are equal on a converging sequence, therefore, as $U \backslash \{ -1 \}$ is open and connected they are equal on this domain.... The identity theorem for holomorphic functions can be applied to any open and connected set, not just on disks.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Note that a holomorphic function on a open and connected set $ U $ of $\mathbb {C}$ is uniquely determined by a non discrete subset of $U$.

Comment: "Univocally determinated" would be more frequently written as "Uniquely determined"

Comment: My english is very bad! xD