# Proving that a function is not holomorphic on the disk

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f \in C(\overline{D(0,1)})$ and $f(\frac{1}{n})=\frac{1}{n+1}$ for $n = 2,3 ...$ Show that $f \notin H(D(0,1))$

Attempted Solution: If I understand the problem correctly, I should show that $f$ is not differentiable on the unit disc centered at the origin. Hence, the limit:

$$ \lim_{z\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(z) -f(0)}{z-0}         $$

does not exist. I'm guessing that I should approach $0$ through the sequence $\frac{1}{n}$ and that should somehow enable me to show that the limit does not exist. But, I don't quite understand how I should go about doing that. Can anyone give me some clues?

Comment: You are approaching this as if it were a problem about real valued functions. In that case you would just obtain that $f(0) = 0, f'(0) = 1$. But you must somehow use that $f$ is holomorphic. See the answer below, which uses the fact that a holomorphic function is uniquely determined by its values on a set of points that has an accumulation point somehere in its domain.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1689994/42969.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zeros of $f(z)-\frac z {z+1}$ have a limit point so the Identity Theorem shows $f(z)=\frac z {z+1}$  in the open disk.   But $\frac z {z+1}$ is not a continuous function on the boundary. [The limit of this function as $z \to -1$ does not exist].